# Как подсчитать процент количества единиц в строке?

Tags: javascript

Стоит задача при вводе параметра, который состоит из рандомного количества нулей и единиц, функция должна возвращать процент количества единиц. Я знаю, как подсчитать количество символов в строке, но мне неизвестен метод, который может подсчитать количество определенных символов в строке. Подскажите вариант решения?

```
function getSuccessRate(statistic){
  
  return statistic.length
}
console.log(getSuccessRate('001101'))
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением `/1/g`, чтобы найти все единицы и затем просто разделить одну длину ну другую:

```
statistic.match(/1/g).length / statistic.length
```

Либо пройтись в цикле по строке и посчитать:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i=0; i < statistic.length; i++) {
    if (statistic[i] == '1') counter = counter + 1;
}

var result = counter / statistic.length
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getSuccessRate(statistic) {
  if (!statistic) {
    return 0;
  } // создадим проверку, если строка пустая возвращаем ноль

  /*посчитаем сколько единиц в нашей строке, 
  переберем все символы с помощью for of*/

  /*если наш текущий символ 1,
  то мы должны его посчитать, создадим счетчик count*/
  let count = 0;
  for (const char of statistic) {
    if (char === '1') {
      count++; // как только найдем 1 то увеличиваем count на единицу
    }
  }
  /* теперь нужно посчитать сколько процентов, 
  для этого возвращаем округленное значение, 
  исп. Math.round(result) для округления до ближайшего целого*/

  /* 1 - берем наше количество единичек(count), 
  2 - делим их на длину строки(statistic.length ) и умножаем на 100 */

  return Math.round((count / statistic.length) * 100);
}


****************************
function getSuccessRate(statistic) {
  if (!statistic) {
    return 0;
  }

  let count = 0;
  for (const char of statistic) {
    if (char === '1') {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return Math.round((count / statistic.length) * 100);
}

console.log(getSuccessRate('001101'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот вариант прошел, собравши по крупицам инфу с нескольких форумов

```
let getSuccessRate = (statistic) => {
  if(statistic === ''){
    return 0
  }
  else{
  let length = statistic.length
  let charSplit = statistic.split('');
  let result = charSplit.filter(char => char === '1');
  return +((result.length/length)*100).toFixed(0);
  }
};
```